# null object in HashTable

Tags: java

When i try `map.get(k)` the index in my hashtable it returns `null` and was wondering if it was my csv to hashtable code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("primes.csv"));
    String line =  null;
    Hashtable<String, String> map = new Hashtable<String, String>(100);

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String str[] = line.split(",");

        map.put(str[0], str[1]);
    }
    br.close();
    System.out.println(map);

    int k;

    k = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(f,"Enter an integer k whee"
            + " 3 < k < 1229: "));

    while (k <= 3 || k >= 1229){
       k = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(f,"Sorry try again: "));
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "The "+ k +"th prime number is " + map.get(k));

}
```

Also my csv file contains

> 1, 1 (next line)
>
> 2, 2 (next line)
>
> 3, 3 (next line)
>
> 4, 5 (next line)
>
> 5, 7 and so on

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `String` keys in your map and you want to retrieve objects from it with  `Integer` keys :

```
String str[] = line.split(",");
...
map.put(str[0], str[1]);
...
int k;
...
map.get(k);
```

It is not possible.
 These are not equals in terms of `equals()`.

So, use the same type as key in both cases.
For example to use `String` in both cases, change the `get()` invocation in this way :

```
map.get(String.valueOf(k));
```

Besides, `Hashtable` is a thread safe class (not efficient too).
You don't need to this feature in your code sample.
A `HashMap` is enough.

Comment: Thank you and I thought the same thing but the professor is requiring a hash table

Comment: You are welcome. It is a pity. While you get the thing, it is fine for you.